# How to translate a structure url

Tags: craft3, localization, url, structure

I'm working on a multilingual website where I have one structure called **Products**. Currently, this structure's URI format is configured like this:

```
{parent.uri ?? section.handle}/{slug}
```

Which returns URLs like this:

```
/products/topLevelProduct1
/products/topLevelProduct1/nestedProduct1
/products/topLevelProduct1/nestedProduct2

/products/topLevelProduct2
/products/topLevelProduct2/nestedProduct1
/products/topLevelProduct2/nestedProduct2

etc
```

The main thing I'm struggling with now is: how do I translate the top-level part of the URI (i.e. `/products`)? I guess I could use the built-in `t()` function on `section.handle` (is that even a good idea?) but that would still be overwritten by `parent.uri`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the URL is specific for each multisite, simply do not use `section.handle` in the structure's URI definition, but go for the term you want as a string instead, e.g.

- English: `{parent.uri ?? 'products'}/{slug}`
- German: `{parent.uri ?? 'produkte'}/{slug}`
- French: `{parent.uri ?? 'produits'}/{slug}`

and so on...

Comment: But then won't `parent.uri` still overwrite whatever I put instead of `section.handle`?

Comment: Yes, it does, but only from the second level of the section and deeper. And since the first level already contains the translated version, this will be inherited to all levels below. `parent.uri ?? 'products'` means: take `parent.uri` if defined and not empty, otherwise go for the the string after `??`. In the 2nd level and deeper, `parent.uri` is defined and will contain the translated string you need.

Comment: Ah of course, that's actually embarrassingly simple. I was so confused as to how `parent.uri` would be generated but it makes complete sense now that I see your explanation. Thanks!